# Pytorch: Custom Layers raising userwarning about the size in the loss criterion

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to adapt my tensorflow to pytorch code. In this case I have the following custom layers:

```
class LinearMax(nn.Module):
   
    __constants__ = ['in_features', 'out_features']
    in_features: int
    out_features: int
    weight: torch.Tensor

    def __init__(self, in_features: int, out_features: int,
                 device=None, dtype=None) -> None:
        factory_kwargs = {'device': device, 'dtype': dtype}
        super().__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.weight = Parameter(torch.empty((out_features, in_features), **factory_kwargs))
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self) -> None:
        # Setting a=sqrt(5) in kaiming_uniform is the same as initializing with
        # uniform(-1/sqrt(in_features), 1/sqrt(in_features)). For details, see
        # https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/57109
        torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
        

    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        inputs_weighted = torch.mul(input, self.weight.T)
        maximum = torch.max(inputs_weighted).unsqueeze(dim=0)
        #print(f"input shape: {input.shape}, weight shape {self.weight.shape}")
        return maximum

    def extra_repr(self) -> str:
        return 'in_features={}, out_features={}'.format(
            self.in_features, self.out_features
        )
```

and the following model:

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.max = layer.LinearMax(1, input_size)
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(1, 8)#, dtype=torch.complex64)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(8, 8)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(8,1)#, dtype=torch.complex64)

    def forward(self, x):
        maximum_out = self.max(x)
        
        out = self.l1(maximum_out)
        
        out = self.relu(out.real)# + 1j * self.relu(out.imag)
        out = self.l2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.l3(out)

        return out
```

By running this part of my code:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data,rul, window):
        self.data = data
        self.rul = rul
        self.window = window

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = torch.from_numpy(self.data[index:index+self.window]).to(torch.float32)
        y = torch.tensor(np.min(self.rul[index:index+self.window])).to(torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)
        
        return x,y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data) - self.window

def training_loop_pytorch(train_loader, model,num_epochs, learning_rate):
    n_total_steps = len(train_loader)
    #loss and optimizer
    criterion = nn.L1Loss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)

    #training loop
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # forward pass and loss
        for i,(vibration, rul) in enumerate(train_loader):
            X = vibration
            y  = rul
            y_predicted = model(X)
            
            #print(y.shape)
            loss = criterion(y_predicted, y)
  #backward pass
            loss.backward()

  # update
            optimizer.step()

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
                print(f'epoch {epoch+1}/ {num_epochs}, step {i+1}/{n_total_steps}, loss={loss.item():.4f}')
    return model
```

I obtain the following userwarning: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([500, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1]))
The code still runs but I wanted to know how I can get remove this warning. When I remove the custom layer the userwarning doesn't appear, so I assume the problem is in the custom layer (but I want to keep it).
Thanks